# Error code 1217, Message: Reduce time between submitting subsequent jobs in a session

Tags: qiskit, programming, qaoa

I tried running a piece of Qiskit code to minimize a Hamiltonian using QAOA. I tried running the same piece of code that I had used earlier in the IBM Quantum system 'ibm_nairobi' which gave me the required results, in the IBM Quantum Systems 'ibm_osaka' and 'ibm_kyoto' separately and every time I tried running it, I got the same error message which says:

```
File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit_ibm_runtime/session.py:180 in run
    job = self._service.run(
  File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit_ibm_runtime/qiskit_runtime_service.py:1009 in run raise IBMRuntimeError(f"Failed to run program: {ex}") from None
IBMRuntimeError: 'Failed to run program: \'400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://api.quantum.ibm.com/runtime/jobs. {"errors":[{"code":1217,"message":"Session has been closed.","solution":"**Reduce time between submitting subsequent jobs in a session."**,"more_info":"https://docs.quantum-computing.ibm.com/errors"}]}\
```

I tried to find resources to resolve the error but couldn't find any. Can someone help?

Edit: I have submitted a single job with multiple shots so I do not have control over the time taken between the two jobs.

Comment: This is probably due to the fact that your `Session` object is kinda old. Try recreating it?

Comment: I am submitting a job in a particular session with multiple shots, I have no control over the time taken between the submission of two jobs.